# How to prevent Auth0-Lock display on redirect?

Tags: meteor, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm using Auth0-Lock with Meteor and when I sign in and confirm connection with Guardian app (2FA), the page redirect me to my app and the auth0-lock appears again.

I had some trouble conditioning the auth0-lock display, and finally came up with this solution :

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
        if(Meteor.loggingIn() == false) {
            if (Meteor.userId() == null) {
                const Lock = initLock();
                Lock.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This allows me to display the auth0-lock when there is no user logged in and prevent its appearing when reloading the page (thanks to `Meteor.loggingIn()`).

But when I accept the guardian push notification and get redirected to my app, `Meteor.loggingIn()` returns `false` and `Meteor.userId()` is not defined yet, so the lock appears just before the user gets logged in.

How could I solve this problem ?